# How to transfer a buffer over a network using C++?

Tags: c++, buffer

I need to transfer a buffer in network, which contains the following:

- 2 bytes which keep the total buffer size
- 2 bytes which keep the size of the header
- Header
- Actual user message

This is how I defined the buffer:

```
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(size_t Capacity);
private:
    uint8_t totalSize[2];
    uint8_t headerSize[2];
    uint16_t header[???];        // incorrect
    uint8_t user[Capacity];
};
```

What I want to do is to send an instance of `Buffer` with something like  `send(reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(&buffer))`.

I know I can use `new` to allocate memory for header and user, but I'm also trying to make the buffer a continuous block in the memory.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as dynamic memory allocation, you can't have dynamically allocated arrays. C++ it should be done using containers or smart pointers to correctly deal with memory allocation and deallocation. Here's the container example:

```
class Buffer{
public:
    //getters and setters
    ...
private:
    uint8_t totalSize[2];
    uint8_t headerSize[2];
    std::vector<uint16_t> header;
}
```

You won't need to deal with capacity, that is, storing it externally, `vector` would handle it for you.

Then you're talking about serialization. It's not that simple in C++, and you can't just take a pointer to memory where class instance is located and transfer it, it would go wrong in so many places, for example, there's padding. You could take a look at [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/) library or write it by yourself.